# Android Studio fullscreen, gray bar

Tags: java, android

I would like to open an android app in full screen. However, I have the problem that I have a gray strip in my screen. I would like to remove this one.

[image: Grey strip at the top]

How can I fix it?

code snippet:

activity xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView blabla />

    <Button bla bla />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity.java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      ...
      ...

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
          getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          ...
          ...
      }
      ...
      ...
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can help you.But i did not understand your problem.

Comment: In the picture you can see a grey stripe at the top. I would like to remove this one and don't now how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to styles.xml and change `.DarkActionBar` for `.NoActionBar`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

becomes

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

if colors are irrelevant to your app, you can actually go for

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

If that does not work try:

Write this in your Activity Java File

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Check Doc here : https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

:)

Comment: It could be so easy.. Thank you very much!!

Comment: If you have any other questions. Please do not hesitate to ask. If my solved your problem please mark it as answered so it can help other people. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You write this code line in onCreate method
before setContentView:

getSupportActionBar().hide().;

;)